# Coercion in JavaScript - Abstract Methods

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, primitive, ecmascript-2016, coercion

I have recently started learning more about coercion in Js and I have been going through the ECMAScript documentation for knowing more about it and how different cases are handled in Js.
While doing I encountered the following statement

```
10-{"a":10,valueOf(){return 8;}}
>2
```

This is the problem along with the output from my browser console can you help me decode how the result comes step by step I did try the simpler version of the same problem which included only the {"a":10} part and thus

```
10-{"a":10}
>NaN
```

understood how the Nan result is obtained but didn't get the first stated problem where the result is 2
Also, one more thing the function valueOf() will return 8 but that will be inside the object's braces isn't it like {"a":10,8}, or is something else happening?
So help me understand why Is result 2?

Comment: `{"a":10,8}` is not a thing. `-{"a":10,valueOf(){return 8;}}` is just `-8`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`10-{"a":10,valueOf(){return 8;}}` is doing `10` minus an object, where the object has a property called `a` with the value `10` (which is irrelevant; it's not used), and a `valueOf` method that returns `8` (which is very relevant :-) ).

The [subtraction operator](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ecmascript-language-expressions.html#sec-subtraction-operator-minus) requires that its operands be numbers. When one of its operands isn't a number, it uses the abstract [ToNumber](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/abstract-operations.html#sec-tonumeric) operation on it to convert it to number. For an object (as in your example), ToNumber uses [ToPrimitive](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/abstract-operations.html#sec-toprimitive) saying its preferred type is "number". In the case of an ordinary object (such as yours), that ends up doing [OrdinaryToPrimitive](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/abstract-operations.html#sec-ordinarytoprimitive). OrdinaryToPrimitive looks to see if the object has certain methods that can be used to get a primitive from the object. When the preferred type is "number," the first method OrdinaryToPrimitive tries is `valueOf`. So that method of your object is called, returns `8`, and `10-8` is performed (resulting in `2`).

Here's that code written more clearly, and without any implicit type conversion:

```js
const obj = {
    // Left `a` off because it's never used for anything
    valueOf() {
        return 8;
    }
};
const numberForObj = obj.valueOf();
console.log(`numberForObj = ${numberForObj}`);
const result = 10 - numberForObj;
console.log(`result = ${result}`);
```

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed explanation, This cleared all of my doubts.

Answer (score 2):

The `a:10` part is insignificant and can be omitted.

When coercing to numbers, objects that provide `valueOf` can use the return value of this function:

```js
var p = { 
   valueOf() {
      return 8;
   } 
}

console.log( +p )
```

Thus, the expression can be simplified to

```js
console.log( 10-{valueOf(){return 8;}} )
```

Answer (score 1):

The first step to understanding what's going on is to understand what [`valueOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/valueOf) does. You can think of it similar to [`toString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString). `toString` is used when an object needs to be turned into string form:

```js
const identity = {
  firstName: "Martha",
  lastName: "Stewart",
  toString() {
    return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
  }
};
console.log("Name: " + identity);
```

`valueOf` is similar, except it's used when an object needs to be turned into a number:

```js
const budget = {
  bank: 3,
  wallet: 5,
  valueOf() {
    return this.bank + this.wallet;
  }
};
console.log(10 + budget);
```